# Unable to restore apps to new Iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, backup, restore

I tried to restore my apps to my new iPhone but 2 of the apps failed to be restored. Then I checked the app store and found out that they are no longer available, maybe Apple took them down. Does that mean I can no longer restore them back into my phone if they are no longer available in the app store? I did fully backed up my phone to the iTunes before.

Answer (score 1):

If they aren't available on the App Store anymore, your phone can't download them from Apple.

If you backed up your phone to iTunes before, you just have to restore the apps from there.

1. Open *iTunes*.
2. Select your device from the menubar at the top.
3. Select *Apps* from the lefthand pane.
4. Check the boxes of the 2 apps you couldn't recover from the App Store and sync them to your mobile device.